# Probability of drawing 2 balls from 3 urns

Tags: probability

We have 3 urns with 10 tokens each, two of them have 3 winning tokens and one has 10 winning tokens.

- One person draws 2 tokens from the same urn, what is the probability that he gets 2 winning tokens? and what is the probability that he gets at least one winning token?
- Another person decides to draw twice from 2 different urns, what is the probability they are both winning tokens?
- The last person draws one token and wins, what is the probability that it was from the urn with 10 winning tokens?

Could somebody please help I am getting very confused by the fact that there are 3 urns and I cant figure out how to build the tree and do the calculations.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: for the first question I know that P(Win)=P(win|I)⋅P(I)+P(win|II)⋅P(II)+P(win|III)⋅P(III). Which is 8/15. But what confuses me is the second token.

Comment: You have the right idea for the first question.  Assume that it is equally likely that a person will select any urn so that $\Pr(I) = \Pr(II) = \Pr(III) = \frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: But what do I do from there?

Comment: For the second question, you need a tree with two levels. The top node has three branches, corresponding to the urn the person drew the first token from. For each possibility, there are then three more branches corresponding to which urn the second marble comes from.

Comment: You should specify whether these three people constitute three separate scenarios or whether they draw from the same three urns one after the other (as "the last person" might seem to indicate).

Answer (score 1):

- The probability of drawing two winning tokens from the first two urns (A and B) is

$$\frac{3}{10}\cdot\frac{2}{9}=\frac{1}{15}.$$

The probability of drawing two winning tokens from the third urn (C) is $1$. If the person is equally likely to choose any urn, the probability of drawing two winning tokens is:

$$P(n=2)=2\cdot\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{15}+\frac{1}{3}=\frac{17}{45}$$

The probability of getting at least one winning token is the same as *not getting 0 tokens*. Appliying the same procedure as above:
$$P(n\geq 1)=1-P(n=0)=1-(2\cdot\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{7}{10}\cdot\frac{6}{9}+\frac{1}{3}\cdot 0)=\frac{31}{45}$$

- In this case, there are 3 possible cases: the player draws the tokens from urns A and B, A and C or B and C. The probability of choosing either of them is $1/3$.

$$P(n=2)=\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{3}{10}\cdot\frac{3}{10}+2\cdot\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{3}{10}\cdot 1=\frac{23}{100}$$

- You can use Bayes' theorem for this exercise:

$$P(A\mid B) = \frac{P(B \mid A) \, P(A)}{P(B)},$$

where $P(A\mid B)$ is the likelihood of event $A$ occurring given that $B$ is true.

$$P(C\mid win)=\frac{P(win\mid C) \, P(C)}{P(win)}=\frac{1 \cdot 1/3}{2 \cdot 1/3\cdot 3/10+1/3\cdot 1}=\frac{5}{8}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the first question. We can easily split this into two cases. The person chooses the urn containing only winning tokens, or he chooses one of the other two urns.

If he draws from the urn with only winning tokens he automatically draws 2 winning tokens. If he draws from one of the other urns he draws 2 winning tokens with probability $\frac{3}{10}\cdot {2}{9}=\frac{1}{15}$.

Now we combine the two by using the probability of getting that urn.
So the probability of finding two tokens when drawing twice from the same urn and choosing the urn uniformly at random:
$$\frac{1}{3} \cdot 1 + \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{15}=\frac{17}{45}$$

Now for the probability of at least one winning token we once again look at the different cases. The urn with only winning token is easy again. For the other urns it is easiest to compute the probability of having no winning tokens and work from there.

The probability of no winning tokens is
$$\frac{7}{10}\cdot \frac{6}{9}=\frac{7}{15}$$
So the probability of at least one winning token becomes $1-\frac{7}{15}=\frac{8}{15}$.

This yields the probability of one or more winning tokens when selecting an urn uniformly at random and drawing from it twice as:
$$\frac{1}{3} \cdot 1 + \frac{2}{3} \frac{8}{15}=\frac{31}{45}$$

- Another person decides to draw twice from 2 different urns, what is the probability they are both winning tokens?

Once again we can split this into 2 cases. Either we draw twice from the urn with mixed tokens or we draw once from the urn with only winning tokens and once from one of the other urns. The last event is twice as likely.

We start with twice from the mixed token urns. The draws are independent so we get
$$\frac{3}{10}\cdot \frac{3}{10}=\frac{9}{100}$$
probability of drawing two winning tokens.

Now for the other case. Clearly we draw a winning token from the one urn. That means that we have probability \frac{3}{10} of drawing two winning tokens for these urns.

Combining them gives the answer to your question:
$$\frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{9}{100} + \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{3}{10}=\frac{23}{100}$$

The last question is unclear to me. What do you mean with the last person? If you can clarify that I can help you with answering that question.